Generating Koltin data classes from Aync api documentation
I am pretty new to async api documentation. In our project we have a repository where we have defined a structure and now we want to generate Kotlin data classes from the async api documentation structure. Is this possible and if yes how can we do that?
Thanks!

Check out our Modelina playground for Kotlin - https://modelina.org/playground?language=kotlin
You can download it's cli and generate needed classes from specification, using selected params
upd:
Something like this:
asyncapi generate models kotlin ./asyncapi.json

Here are instruction, to customize generation process - https://github.com/asyncapi/modelina?tab=readme-ov-file#what-does-modelina-do
